# how do I use the || operator inside a class to set a default value?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that accesses a window object:

```
class foo {
  bar = window.bar
}
```

if window.bar doesn't exist, my app crashed with

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
```

I try to prevent this by using the || operator to set a default value:

```
class foo {
  bar = window.bar || 'error, bar doesn't exist'
}
```

However, I still get the TypeError when window.bar doesn't exist. How do I correctly do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't that `window.bar` doesn't exist, it's that `window` doesn't exist.

Maybe try something like `typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.bar ? window.bar : 'error, bar doesn't exist'`

Comment: I just tested using that and got the same TypeError.

Comment: @DavidC Sorry, you'll have to use typeof to check if `window` exists. See my revised answer.

Comment: Actually my problem was that the object i'm accessing is nested, like window.foo.bar, I tested window && window.foo.bar ? ... and it didn't work, i realized the purpose was to make sure the parent exist, so i changed it to window && window.foo ? ... and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: the original answer was correct, i just had to target the parents of the object i'm accessing. Thanks.